# func(*args, **kwargs, x) throwing invalid syntax

Tags: python

Studied myself into a corner again...

```
def superfunction(*args, **kwargs, k):
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Whats the rule Im breaking here? It seems that youre not supposed to mix 'regular' variables with * variables, but I cant find anyone to confirm or deny this. I read somewhere (and I cant find in now of course) that some types of arguments have to come first, I believe keyword arguments, which may or may not be part of my issue.

Comment: The details of exactly why this is wrong are a bit different between Python 2.x and 3.x; see the tutorial section [Keyword Arguments](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) and the reference section [Function definitions](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#function) for your appropriate version have the details. But briefly, nothing can come after the `**` parameter.

Comment: I've also got a [blog post](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/08/arguments-and-parameters.html) that explains the full details; I don't think it's at all novice-friendly… but I hope it's at least a little easier than reading the reference docs. (It is Python 3-specific, however.)

Answer (score 18):

Try this:

```
def superfunction(k, *args, **kwargs):
```

The `**kwargs` variable keyword parameter must be the last part in the function declaration. Second-to-last, the `*args` variable position parameter. (In Python 3.x only, you can also have keyword-only parameters between `*args` and `**kwargs`.) And in the first places, the positional parameters - that's the correct way to declare function parameters. Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs) for additional details.

For the full reference, see the Function definitions section in [Python 3.x](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function) or [Python 2.x](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#function).

Comment: so its unnamed vars, named vars, *, **

Comment: The only order I can get it to work in is def superfunction(k, n = 2 , *args, **kwargs): Thank you for putting me on the right track.

Comment: followup : def superfunction(k, n = 2 , *args, *args2, **kwargs): Having multiple * type arguments throws a syntax error too. I guess youre only allowed one?

Comment: This isn't quite right for Python 3.x, because you can also have keyword-only arguments between the `*args` and `**kwargs`. But either way, you can't have anything after the `**kwargs`, and you can't have more than one `*args` or more than one `**kwargs`.

Comment: That's right, only one is allowed. I edited my answer with an useful link

Comment: Thank you Oscar. Reading it now. To anyone struggling with *args, read *args as 'multiple arguments' and it makes sense (to me anyway).

Comment: Your answer used "arguments" where it should have used "parameters". I've edited it; feel free to revert if you disagree.

Comment: @jason: Exactly, the `*args` parameter takes all the excess positional arguments, and `**kwargs` takes all the excess keyword arguments, so it doesn't makes sense to have positional parameters after `*args`, or _any_ kind of parameters after `**kwargs`, or two of either.

Comment: @abarnert no need to revert, I agree :)

Comment: Keyword only parameters between `*args` and `**kwargs` are allowed also in 2.6 and 2.7

Comment: @NicolaMusatti: Are you sure? The [2.7 reference](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#function) doesn't allow it (compare it to the 3.x version), the release notes don't say anything about it, `def foo(a, *b, c=2, **d): pass` raises a `SyntaxError` in 2.7, and [PEP 3102](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/) has version 3.0 as the target.

Comment: Sorry, I confused *defining* middle keyword-only arguments with *using* them. The latter is indeed possible in 2.6 and 2.7 (but not 2.5)

Answer (score 4):

Syntax should be like this:

```
def superfunction(k, *args, **kwargs):
```

First you give all the positional arguments, then non-keyword arguments, and then keyword arguments.

Comment: Besides getting arguments and parameters wrong… non-keyword arguments and positional arguments are the same thing, so this is confusing and wrong.

Comment: The right order is: positional-or-keyword params, then optionally `*args` (or `*`, in Python 3.x only), then (in Python 3.x only) keyword-only params, then `**kwargs`.

Comment: @abarnert Ah! Is it? I read it few months back, so I seem to forgot the technical term, and hence a mix-up. Thanks for pointing that out.